# search text within a webView doesn't work

Tags: android, webview

I'm using [this code](http://devemat-androidprogramming.blogspot.it/2012/03/search-text-within-webview.html)  to search words within in a textView.
The buttons and the EditText are displayed but they don't work.
In the code there is a warning that says

> The method `findAll(String)` from the type `WebView` is deprecated

for the line

> `wv.findAll(findBox.getText().toString());`

The rest of the code is in [this link](http://devemat-androidprogramming.blogspot.it/2012/03/search-text-within-webview.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
wv.findAll(findBox.getText().toString());
```

for API versions < 16 and Use

```
wv.findAllAsync(findBox.getText().toString());
```

for API versions > 16.

Use the following code to ensure that your code works on all versions:

```
int API = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(API < 16) {
    wv.findAll(findBox.getText().toString());
} else {
    wv.findAllAsync(findBox.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: The `findAll` method works in Android 2.2, you need to use both methods for different API versions. Use my code that has both in it. See this for more info http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#findAll(java.lang.String)